# cron job does not work in cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel, jobs

I have put this command line in Cpanel cronjob

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /public_html/myfolder/directory/admin/cron.php
```

and got this error

```
Could not open input file: /public_html/myfolder/directory/admin/cron.php
```

I have checked, the file is there in the folder. This is basically a script that sends a login 
reminder to every member of the MySQL database. The script runs successfully if I launch it from the URL in browser.

Answer (score 4):

Use full path:

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/myfolder/directory/admin/cron.php
```

Or simply use `get` the URL :

```
GET http://example.com/myfolder/directory/admin/cron.php
```